# How can I make a Hive table from a .csv file which has one column with fields delimiited by semicolon ;

Tags: mysql, csv, hadoop, hive, beeswax

I have a .csv file in the format of having one(first) column/cell with the five fields I want in my hive table separated by a semicolon ; like so:

```
ISBN;"Title";"Author";"Year";"Publisher"
0002005018;"Clara Callan";"Richard Bruce Wright";"2001";"HarperFlamingo Canada"
0399135782;"The Kitchen God's Wife";"Amy Tan";"1991";"Putnam Pub Group"

etc. 
etc.
...
```

Can I use a Hive query to split the data by ; and store it in a table which I have created with the same order of Column names?

Like regexp_extract? Or do i need to use serde?

I am new to Hadoop/hive/beeswax and am using the Cloudera-quickstart vm 5.2

Comment: It would be better to use SerDe, You can find example [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-ApacheWeblogData)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE books (ISBN STRING, Title STRING, Author STRING, Year STRING, Publisher STRING)
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\;";
LOAD DATA INPATH '/path/to/your/datafile' INTO TABLE books;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but could you explain why the YEAR field cannot be INT in this query? 
It comes up as NULL when it is INT.

Comment: I believe it's the fact that years in your data are surrounded by quotation marks.  Removing the quotes should allow the data to be loaded directly into an INT column.

Comment: Thanks, also my data is being misread sometimes as it is being split prematurely on the &amp; (ampersand code i think) in some rows in the table. How can I stop this from happening?



Basically some titles have &amp; and all the columns become incorrect after it for that row.

Comment: Others may have different opinions, but my perspective is that since you're likely using Hive/HDFS as a data warehouse, you should have performed at least a cursory amount of sanitization upon the data prior to loading it (clean out the ampersands prior to loading into HDFS and Hive).  Alternately, inhale the entirety of each line as a single column into a staging table in Hive and post-process it into the format you want.